# soulation for two language phonegap app

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, cordova, phonegap-plugins

what the best sample for two language phonegap app?
i want to set default language (index-en.html or index-fa.html) and theme by user in first used and save selected user settings. What is the best possible way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

For client side internationalization I can recommend [i18next](https://github.com/i18next/i18next).
You can just create two resourcefiles with JSON objects and use them for your static text. That way you don't have to maintain two html files, which I can imagine would be very frustrating.

Using i18next is pretty simple.

You just place a `data-i18n` attribute to the element like this:
 
`<span class="my-class" data-i18n="my.key"></span>`
 
And make it do its magic like this:
 
`$(".my-class").i18n();`

If you are using Handlebars as a template engine it is even better, you just need to:
`{{t "my.key" }}`.

You can of course use it programmatically like this:
`var myKey = t("my.key");`

If you have a large project with a lot of static content, you may want to maintain the translations in other format like Excel and then use some kind of tool to convert it to JSON.